# How do you save the file that you're working on as a new file?

Tags: save

There are times when I want to test changes to a file before I overwrite the original.
Is there any way I can save a file being edited to a new file?

Comment: The off-topic answer would be to suggest a VCS. For instance git's index might be useful

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can give a parameter to the `:w` or `:write` command to save to a different file.
For example to save the current buffer to `/tmp/data.txt`:

```
:w /tmp/data.txt
```

However, keep in mind that this does not switch your buffer to that other file.
So if you keep editing and do just `:w`, that will save to the current file, not to the other one. To switch to the other file, use the `:edit` command:

```
:e /tmp/data.txt
```

To do this one step, save to another file and switch to it, use the `:saveas` command:

```
:sav /tmp/data.txt
```

Comment: It's also good to keep in mind that vim will complain if you make any changes to the current buffer without saving/writing them to the current file before running `e: /tmp/data.txt`

Comment: But, I suppose `:sav` overrides writing changes to the original file so it essentially combines `:w` and `:e!`.

Answer (score 6):

Vim has a "backup mode" that can be enabled by `:set backup` or `:set patchmode`.  In that mode, Vim automatically keeps a backup copy of files that you write.

For example, if you issue `:set patchmode=.orig`, and you edit an existing file `somefile.txt`, then when you issue `:w` normally, Vim will keep a copy of the old file as `somefile.txt.orig` and save the new contents as `somefile.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way.
`:w new_file_name`

Answer (score 0):

Simply specify a newfilepath at the `:w` command - `:w newfile.foo`